# How to group Path objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating some 'map application' in WPF, using C#. I use Visual Blend 2 to draw boundaries of countries, so as a result I got Path objects (written in XAML). Path is an object where the first point == last point, so path is always closed. Some countries (like Japan) has some islands, so as a result one country has more than 1 path.

I am trying to add some behaviors to those objects (countries - so 1 or more paths), like when user mouse is enter some country (or IsMouseOver property is 'true' - but it doesn't matter here), country is changing their background color.

Where some country == 1 path, there is no problem. But what can I do where there are more than 1 path to some countries?

So my question is: **how to group paths in one object?**

I was trying to use GeometryGroup class but I can't use it properly...

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path can have more than one 'M' no problem and it works fine with path.Fill. Ultimately it depends on a type of figure you're drawing.

Here's a sample:

```
<Path Data="M10,10 h100 v100 h-100z M30,30 h50 v50 h-50z" 
     Stroke="Gray" 
     StrokeThickness="1" 
     Fill="Blue"/>
```

or `Geometry.Parse("M10,10 h100 v100 h-100z M30,30 h50 v50 h-50z")` if you use code.

Comment: Thank you, it will help me a lot :) Actually I had some other problem here, because Expression Blend is creating different 'Margin' property to all paths, so I will need to take it into consideration, but I will use your advice. I wrote this because I had not enough rank points to vote up for you. But thanks again :)

Comment: You're grand, ny questions shout.

Answer (score 1):

Create a plain C# class to use as a logical model for a country. Then it could contain a `List<Path> CountryBoundaries` instance-variable, which it would manage the background colors for.

Then you need to hook-up mouseover-events of the paths to the correct country.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about store them in a class. Thanks.